# ajax in colorbox and array of html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox

I'm trying to force colorbox to work with array of htmls given by ajax response, but still it does not work.

javascript code:

```
$.post($('#createForm').attr('action'),{
        'id' : 1
    },function(data){
        var $trash = $('<div>').hide().appendTo('body');

        $.each(data, function(i){
            $(data[i]).appendTo($trash);
            alert(data[i]);
        });

        $trash.find('div').colorbox({rel:'mygroup', open:true});
    }, 'json');
```

php code:

```
    $content = '<div class="page" rel="mygroup"><p class="kkk">item1</p></div>';
    $content2 = '<div class="page" rel="mygroup"><p class="kkk">item2</p></div>';
    $return = json_encode(array($content, $content2));
    return new Response($return);
```

response is correct, becouse alerts work correct. I need to present a html document consisting of multiple pages.

I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using json altoghther, insert all pages to general div like that `<div class="container><div class="page" rel="mygroup"><p class="kkk">item1</p></div><div class="page" rel="mygroup"><p class="kkk">item2</p></div></div>` and than in js part use this:

```
$.post($('#createForm').attr('action'),{
    'id' : 1
},function(data){
    var $trash = $('<div>').hide().appendTo('body');

   $(data).children().each(function(i){
        $(this).appendTo($trash);
        alert($(this).html());
    });

    $trash.find('div').colorbox({rel:'mygroup', open:true});
});
```

it will alert inner values of html blocks but other than that will do what you need